# 480v Single Phase forklift battery charger wiring?

Tags: voltage, wiring, charger

[image]I recently have been asked to install a battery charger that came along with a forklift purchase.  It is a 480volt 1ph charger.  It has terminals labled L1,N,G.  The plant is wired 480v 3ph, with 277v for lighting, and 120v common outlets.  How do I wire this thing???  I have no 480v neutral.  Thanks!!!

Comment: L1 = Phase A, N = Phase B, G = Ground? Do you have a datasheet, wiring diagrams, or schematics for the charger?

Comment: Perhaps it may have been worth asking if they did a 3 phase charger...

Comment: This is a "look what we bought without asking you first" kinda deal.

Answer (score 3):

- Set all the charger tap changers to 480 V.
- Create a supply from two phases with a suitable 2-pole miniature circuit breaker. Note that the charger is only fused on the live so the external fusing is essential.
- Power the charger as shown in Table 1.

*Table 1. Wiring connections.*

```
Supply  Charger
------  -------
   L1      L
   L2      N
   L3      n/c
   N       n/c
   PE      PE
```

Comment: Alright... I was hesitant about wiring a hot phase to the neutral terminal.

Comment: If you look at that schematic, the "Neutral" only goes to two transformers, so it is electrically equivalent to the Line lead.

Comment: yeah, and both L and N pass through the relay contacts, they could have labeled them L1 and L2 and saved a lot of confusion.

Comment: @Jasen, not without putting a fuse on L2 to protect against a phase to frame short circuit.